# vTiger back to install page

Tags: installation, vtiger

I successfully uploaded all the vtiger 6.1.0 on my ftp server. During the installation, something went wrong. (I had to increase execution time). I deleted all my database tables (in phpMyAdmin) but now I have a white screen instead of the install screen.

What files do I have to delete so vtiger goes back to the installion process? (without uploading all the files again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

set the default config.inc.php file and delete config.csrf-secret.php

Recommended server settings:

```
memory_limit = 512m
max_execution_time = 6000
max_input_time = 6000
```